# C# list box new lines

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to print new lines on a list box in windows form, but /n or /r/n is not working to print in different lines.
It all prints as a single element

Comment: Are you actually using "/n" and "/r/n"? Those won't work, but "\r\n" should...

Comment: Do we have to change the property of the listbox to allow multiple lines?

Comment: You could also use Environment.NewLine instead of "\r\n" to get the new line that is defined for the current environment.

Answer (score 4):

.NET windows forms standard listbox does not support multi line items.

to get what you describe you either use another control or customize the ListBox to work differently.

have a look at this link: [An editable multi-line listbox for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/nishmullinlisbox.aspx) for an example

also have a look at this other one, still about extending controls with Owner Drawn approach: [Owner Drawn Controls - Extendable ListBox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ExtendedListBoxControl.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Regex.Split to split up your string to multiple lines like this:

```
foreach (string s in Regex.Split(TheStringContainigTheNewLines, "\n"))
    lbMyListBox.Items.Add(s);
```