# Windows Forms - List Dialog String Builder Append New Line

Tags: c#, winforms, newline, stringbuilder

I have searched for about half an hour across Google for the answer to my question yet no one seems to have posted any solutions. I am working on a Windows Forms Application and have a `ListDialogBox` that doesn't seem to accept any of the methods I have tried to display a new line when I am adding display items with a `StringBuilder`

Code snippet:

```
public string VehicleInfo()

    // StringBuilder and List of Vehicles
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    List<Vehicle> _vehicles = new List<Vehicle>(Vehicle v1, Vehicle v2, and so on...);

    foreach (Vehicle v in _vehicles)
    {
        sb.Append(v.VIN);
        sb.Append(v.Make);
        sb.Append(v.Model);
        sb.Append(v.Year);
        sb.Append(v.Color);
        sb.Append(v.License);

        // Here is what I have tried
        sb.Append("\n");
        sb.Append("\\n");
        sb.Append("\r\n"); // Edit (I've tried this as well)
        sb.AppendLine();
        sb.AppendLine(Environment.NewLine);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

And then I am adding display items to the list dialog box

```
ListDialog ld = new ListDialog();

ld.AddDisplayItems(Owner.ToString()); // The Owner to list Vehicles for
ld.AddDisplayItems(Owner.VehicleInfo()); // The list of vehicles the owner has

ld.ShowDialog();
```

As you can see I am working with vehicle and owner classes, part of a **Vehicle Registration System** project in my Software Architecture and Design course. The simple objective in this case is displaying the information about an **Owner** followed by information about each of the **Vehicles** he/she owns.

The `StringBuilder` seems to just add each string of **Vehicle** info onto the end of the preceding, ignoring all of my intentions to produce a new line for each one.

Any help and/or advice is appreciated!

Comment: Use `sb.AppendLine(retValue)`, and then return `sb.ToString()` from the function, and that will get you one line per vehicle.

Comment: and then you won't need to add `Environment.NewLine` to your format string.

Comment: Just tried it, doesnt work either. I have found concluded that there is no solution per (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105817/c-sharp-list-box-new-lines)

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code is a bit confusing.

```
 foreach (Vehicle v in _vehicles)
    {
        sb.Append(_vehicle.VIN);
```

Is it v or _vehicle? This code wouldn't even compile as-is, unless you have a _vehicle field, in which case you're repeatedly writing the wrong information to the StringBuilder.

```
// Here is what I have tried
sb.Append("\n");
```

If you want to add one line per property, use AppendLine like this:

```
sb.AppendLine(_vehicle.VIN);
```

If you want to add a new line after adding the other properties just call AppendLine() without any arguments:

```
 sb.Append(_vehicle.VIN);
 sb.Append(_vehicle.Make);
 sb.Append(_vehicle.Model);
 sb.AppendLine();
```

Bear in mind though this will create a string like "123456FordEscort", is that what you want?

Also:

```
ListDialog ld = new ListDialog();
```

What's a ListDialog?

Comment: I also have commas and labels for each of the properties...The properties are all strings, and I am not trying to Append each property to a new line, I want one line to contain the info for one vehicle (VIN, Make, Model, etc.). I do have a field called _vehicles which I declared just above the foreach loop. Imagine a List which contains Vehicle objects. Each of the methods described in the second half were attempts at adding a new line.

Comment: A ListDialog is Windows Form and the AddDisplayItems() method refers to the ListBox inside of that form.

Comment: Hi Joe, you may have a field called _vehicles, but your foreach loop specifies each *v* in _vehicles, then your inner code references *_vehicle*..

Comment: Caught that kinda late..Thanks - Corrected

Comment: Are you sure the ListBox class support text with multiple lines?

Comment: It may not...That's what I am trying to confirm